# How to call silde-out Menu from other class in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, slider, amslidemenu

I am building an application where I am using AMSlideMenu Library for sliding-out menu. Now I have implement an tab bar and I have added an button programmatically on top.

Now I need on that button `IBaction` that left slider open.

Below is slid-out class function that I wanna to use in class of tab bar.

```
- (CGFloat)leftMenuWidth {
    return 265; }


- (void)configureLeftMenuButton:(UIButton *)button {
    CGRect frame = button.frame;
    frame.origin = (CGPoint){0,0};
    frame.size = (CGSize){30,30};
    button.frame = frame;

    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-menu"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }

//- (void)configureRightMenuButton:(UIButton *)button //{ //    CGRect frame = button.frame; //    frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 13); //    button.frame = frame; //    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"simpleMenuButton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //}

//- (void) configureSlideLayer:(CALayer *)layer //{ //    layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor; //    layer.shadowOpacity = 1; //    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0); //    layer.shadowRadius = 5; //    layer.masksToBounds = NO; //    layer.shadowPath =[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.layer.bounds].CGPath; //}

- (UIViewAnimationOptions) openAnimationCurve {
    return UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut; }

- (UIViewAnimationOptions) closeAnimationCurve {
    return UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut; }


// Enabling Deepnes on left menu
- (BOOL)deepnessForLeftMenu {
    return NO; }
```

Please help me.